# Congratulations, Law is now graduated!

Tags: discussion, beta

It's a big day, [and this was announced a bit earlier](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/425/congrats-law-se-will-be-graduating-soon). It's taken a bit longer than intended to get the switches rolling (in part because some fellow whose name happens to match the author of this post got wrapped up in too many election snoobles), but we've thrown up all the switches that occur for design independent graduation.

Graduation works in two phases, as basically explained in the previous announcement. To expand what's happening today.

- You will soon have an election for community-voted moderators - yours is scheduled to begin on July 18th, which is in two weeks.
- You will no longer see the "beta" label attached to your site's name. This is already active.
- You will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the network. This is already active.
- You will soon be able to select your own community ads. My plan is to get these up today, along with a few others across the network alongside SO's halfway-through-the-year reset, but if not today, it'll be tomorrow. And please do not hesitate to badger me if it takes longer.

  - The site will still receive a full design from one of our designers, which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege.

This site has reached this point because of your generous contributions. Together, you've created a valuable resource that helps people. Congratulations on all you've accomplished.

Comment: It was great to login today and see the "beta" label missing!!

Comment: Ooh! Yippie! Hooray!

Comment: Huzzah! Fantastic work, everyone :)

Comment: That was pretty fast.  It makes me wonder why it was such a pain to get Law as a proposal up and running in the first place.

Comment: Congratulations!!

Comment: Great. Now I vote for a Judge Dredd themed site redesign.

Comment: @PatW. MISSING: The Beta Label. Possibly kidnapped by "Stack Exchange, Inc."

Answer (score 7):

### Thank You.

Thank you to everyone.

Thank you to the [awesome law moderators](https://law.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) who keep this site in check. And can graduate in near record time (you need to secretly tell me those trade secrets so I can use them in [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com)!)

Thank you to the community who can write such awesome answers, and write such insightful questions where everyone can learn more from. I seriously look up to all you folks, you folks know nearly everything in the legal field. I really mean that!

Thank you to Stack Exchange for having such a wonderful platform to raise a community.

And now I'm tired of *Thank You's*...

So... Cookies for all to celebrate!

[image]