# Can we get a cool icon?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-planned

Instead of the boring "L" in a box.

Suggestions:

- A gavel
- Lady justice
- A big book with 'Law' on it
- Scales

Comment: Please *NOT* a gavel.  At least in England and Wales (and I believe Scotland too), they are not used by judges or magistrates at all.  (Many UK citizens having seen more US-based legal dramas than UK are not aware of this.)

Answer (score 2):

This will happen when it's our turn! We graduated a bit over a year ago and there's quite a backlog for site designs, so hopefully it'll happen for us soon ™

[Congratulations, Law is now graduated!](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/480/58)

Comment: It's been a while, any news?