# Why does Law.SE not have any artwork?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It seems odd to me that Law.SE does not have any artwork for the site. I understand that symbols of law can vary by region, but there should be something like a gavel that could cover the vast majority of legal systems. Is this a work in progress, an intentional decision, or forgotten in in the mix of things?

Answer (score 5):

The time until a site gets a design varies a lot. I'll copy the data that was last update in October 2017 from [How long until graduated sites get a new site design and increased privileges threshold?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290363/352819):

> - **Graduation Dates:** [Timeline of SE sites](https://normalhuman.github.io/timeline/), which gets the dates directly through the SE API
> - **Design Dates:** Site's Meta for announcements of new designs.
>
> The duration confirms that "it varies". The sites with '?' are still waiting for their design.
>
> Site                                Graduation Design      Duration  Link to Site Design Announcement

```
Blender                             2015-06-16  2016-01-28  7 months  https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1021/new-site-design-is-live
Network Engineering                 2015-06-23  2015-06-23  same day  https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/507/site-graduated-new-design-launched
Cryptography                        2015-06-30  2015-12-21  6 months
Code Review                         2015-07-14  2015-11-25  4 months
Computer Science                    2015-08-18  2016-02-01  5 months
Anime & Manga                       2015-08-25  ?   
Magento                             2015-09-01  2016-02-26  6 months    
English Language Learners           2015-09-08  2016-02-25  6 months
Japanese Language                   2015-09-09  2016-06-08  9 months
Music: Practice & Theory            2015-09-09  2016-03-30  7 months
Software Recommendations            2015-09-09  2016-04-22  7 months
Worldbuilding                       2015-11-16  2016-05-17  6 months
Signal Processing                   2015-11-16  2016-10-05  11 months
Aviation                            2015-11-16  2016-07-01  7 months
Emacs                               2015-11-16  2016-05-24  6 months
Raspberry Pi                        2015-11-17  2015-11-17  same day
Programming Puzzles & Code Golf     2016-02-23  ?   
Puzzling                            2016-05-04  2016-05-04  same day
Philosophy                          2016-07-06  ?   
Law                                 2016-07-06  ?   
Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair  2016-09-13  ?   
Quantitative Finance                2016-12-12  ?   
Ethereum                            2017-06-26  ?
Data Science                        2017-07-10  ?
Arduino                             2017-07-17  ?
Bitcoin                             2017-10-09  ?
```

The specific entry for Law.SE states:

```
Law                                 2016-07-06  ?
```

This means that there is no date so far on that unofficial list for when Law.SE will get a design.

You can see that Law.SE was told they'd get a design in the official graduation post [Congratulations, Law is now graduated!](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/480/17772):

> The site will still receive a full design from one of our designers, which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege.

In the corresponding [announcement post](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/425/congrats-law-se-will-be-graduating-soon) you can see that the design was intended to be done later because designing a site is a lot of work:

> The design comes later only because it takes a lot more work than the other bits, and we've come to realize that it doesn't make sense to hold up the rest of the good stuff just to wait on one piece of awesome. Stay tuned to meta if you want to be the first to know about design news!

If you are looking through Law.SE Meta with the search [design is:q](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=design+is%3Aq) to find questions that contain the word "design" you find that there are no other relevant post on this meta so far.

That means the answer to the question is: it's in the work. Probably. So far there hasn't been an official public announcement about the design of Law.SE and many other sites are also waiting for a design. That's part of the reason for the [Ch-ch-ch-changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/352819) regarding the design of the network last year - they want to make things easier to be able to give more sites a design.

Comment: "*data that was last update in October 2017*" AFAIK, it's the latest data; no new design since then :) **However,** the design team has restarted the site design project, starting from (the inevitable) [Anime.SE](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4229). So, keep your fingers crossed for site design on Law.SE!